# How can I optimize loading content to a UITableView while downloading the content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, loading

Is it faster for Swift (UIKit) to handle table view sections or rows?

For example, if I am building a table view with many parts, should I place each differentiation of content in rows or sections?

Currently, I am facilitating this with sections and headers, but the scrolling gets laggy when loading content from the internet..

Comment: In my opinion, using sections as your rows or using rows as your rows will not make a big difference as they are both reusable views. It depends mostly on what is in view and when you scroll, the cells (be it sections or rows) get recycled. I feel the bottleneck might be in the networking aspect which might be happening synchronously on the main thread. May I ask what kind of data are you loading ?

Comment: Images. I perfected the scroll in about 4 hours time today, utilizing SDWebImage, & heightForRow in UITableViewDelegate.